# Hotkey for YouTube video to a playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I am looking for a way easily to queue up several videos into the "watch it later" playlist.  I want something better then simply visiting the page for each video, and manually clicking the "Add to" button.

My current workflow is: browse through a list of videos in Google Reader, click the link to open the videos I want to watch in a new tab, for each opened video I click the "Add to" button, and then once I have queued up the videos I am interested in, I watch them.

I have lots of spare programmable keys on [my keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GP844S), so if there is a hotkey assigned to the add to button, or if a hotkey could be added via user script, that would be good.

I have a mouse [gesture plugin](http://easygestures.mozdev.org/) that permits me to execute JavaScript, which basically executes as if I had called a bookmarklet.  So a simple bookmarklet to add the current video to the playlist would be an improvement.

It would be even better, if someone could suggest a method to add a video to a playlist directly while I am viewing the feed in Google Reader.  I would be very happy if I could completely skip the step of opening the page for the video, and directly add something to the playlist from within Google Reader.

I subscribe to channel/user feeds using a URLs like these:

**New videos for a user**
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/username/newsubscriptionvideos
**New favorites for a user**
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/username/favorites
**New uploads for a user**
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/username/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile

**Example**: 
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/sourcefed/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile

Answer (score 2):

You can just hover over the video and an icon like this...

[image]

The top one, the clock, will add it to your "watch later" list

and the one beneath it with the three lines and arrow adds the video to your queue

You can do this directly from the feed while looking at YouTube videos when you hover over the video. This works int he new YouTube layout so if you are still using the old YouTube layout I'm not sure how that would work.

There is also three dots usually next to a video anywhere on YouTube and when you press it this pops up...

[image]

(Add to queue, Save to Watch later, Save to playlist, and Report)

You can press any of the three and it will add the video to a playlist